# PHP - inserting a date into the database results in wrong date format?

Tags: php, database, date

I have this query represented as a string (its shortened to make it easier to read):

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO mytable (ke_voucher_date) VALUES (\'%s\')';
```

Now this is what I do next:

```
$query = vsprintf($query, array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $params));
mysql_query($query);
```

$params is an array holding all values that should be saved, in this case (because its shortened) only the date in the format dd.mm.yyyy (21.04.2012). The result is 21.04.2026 for example. Whats wrong with the code, ideas? Maybe the %s?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I'm aware, MySQL requires YYYY-mm-dd format.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html - Can you please explain why you use that date format and why do you expect it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"21.04.2012" is not a format MySQL likes. You should always format your dates as `Y-m-d`, e.g. `2012-04-21`.

> Although MySQL tries to interpret values in several formats, date parts must always be given in year-month-day order (for example, '98-09-04'), rather than in the month-day-year or day-month-year orders commonly used elsewhere (for example, '09-04-98', '04-09-98').